# Do splitters for mac combined mic/headphones exist?

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone

I am looking for a splitter that turns my 3.5mm headphone and mic port on my Mac mini into two 3.5mm headphone and mic ports or one audio out port and one audio out/mic port.

I want to be able to leave my speakers plugged in and use my headphones/mic at the the same time. I will turn off speakers when using headphones and mic, but don't want to keep reaching around to plug and unplug.

I was unable to find anything that does what I want. Most splitters seem to only split the combined port into one audio out and one mic port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the ["Wiretap" from Extrasensory devices](https://makers4good.com/pages/wiretap)?

[image: Wiretap diagram]
<sub>(source: [shopify.com](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0216/6508/products/wiretap_golden_1024x1024.png?v=1362078881))</sub>